# Delocalization in the square root version of Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, causality, klein-gordon-equation, non-locality

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics) Wikipedia article a relativistic wave equation is derived using the Hamiltonian
 $$H=\sqrt{\textbf{p}^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}$$
Substituting this into the Schrödinger equation gives the square root version of the Klein-Gordon equation:
$$\left( \sqrt{ (-i \hbar \nabla)^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4 } \right) \psi = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi$$
Then the article says:

> Another problem, less obvious and more severe, is that it can be shown to be nonlocal and can even violate causality: if the particle is initially localized at a point $r_0$ so that $\psi(r_0 ,t=0)$ is finite and zero elsewhere, then at any later time the equation predicts delocalization $\psi(r,t)\neq 0$ everywhere, even for $r>ct$ which means the particle could arrive at a point before a pulse of light could.

What is this solution explicitly?
I have read also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156124/) Phys.SE question but there is no clue for my question.

Comment: I think this question is related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195143/

Answer (score 2):

Taking from Peskin & Schroeder p.14:
[image: Propagation amplitude]

They then calculate it asymptotically, and refer to:  Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (1980), #3.914 for an exact solution
Searching that reference, we come across: #3.914, 6: (Available [here](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~ib38/tmp/reading/Table_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products_Tablicy_Integralov_Summ_Rjadov_I_Proizvedennij_Engl._2.pdf))
[image: Calculation]
Where $K_2$ is the modified Bessel function.

Comment: that solution is also a solution of the Klein-Gordon equation. So that would imply that the standard Klein-Gordon equation is non-local too. am I right?

Comment: "Quantum field theory solves the causality problem in a miraculous way which we will discuss in Section 2.4.  We will find that in the multiparticle field theory the propagation of a particle across a spacelike interval is indistinguishable from the propagation of an antiparticle in the opposite direction see (Fig 2.1). When we ask whether an observation made at point x can affect an observation made at point x we will find that the amplitudes for particle and antiparticle propagation exactly cancel--so causality is preserved." - Taken from P&S later on.

Comment: The solution doesn't vanish outside the light cone, and therefore the solution is non-local, but, due to anti-particles, causality is preserved.

Comment: But this would be a problem for the K-G equation too.

Comment: If causality is preserved, it's not really that big of a problem.

Comment: But (acording to the book) causality problem is solved using QFT. My quetion is just about the equations. K-G equation (which is second order in time derivatives and space derivatives) and the square root version. Some people call them local and non-local respectively.

Comment: So, K-G equation admits a nonlocal solution too.

Comment: The KG equation itself has this problem, that much is true. However, when using it in QFT, causality is preserved. So while the equation itself has this problem, it is later solved.