# Amplitude for a string to propagate from one point to another

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, string-theory, causality, non-locality

In Zwiebach’s book sections 12.6 and 12.7 interesting aspects of the wave function of the string are discussed. In order to introduce my question first recall what happens with the relativistic particle. In this case the Hamiltonian:
$$H_P=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$$
The amplitude for the particle to propagate from $x_0$ to $x$ is:
$$ \langle x |e^{-iH_P t} |x_0\rangle \sim e^{-m\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}$$
See for instance Peskin’s book$^1$ for the details.

Now, back to the string. It would be interesting to obtain a similar calculation for the string. As in Zwiebach’s book, the Hamiltonian is
$$H=L_0^\perp -1$$
But the useful basis would be $ |x^-,x_T \rangle $ instead of $ |p^+,p_T \rangle $ (see page 263). So the amplitude for the center of mass of the string to propagate from $x$ to $y$ would be:
$$ \langle y^-,y_T |e^{-iH t} |x^-,x_T \rangle $$
If this is nonzero outside the light-cone, the result would be similar to relativistic quantum mechanics. The center of mass of the string can arrive at a point before a pulse of light. So my question is about this last expression, has someone calculated it? Is this a problem for string theory?

---

$^1$ Peskin & Schroeder; Introduction to Quantum Field Theory; page 14.