# Schrodinger equation using relativistic kinetic energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I have seen work with introducing relativistic corrections to the momentum term of the Hamiltonian by taking higher order terms in the Taylor series, but do people work with $H = \sqrt{P^2 c^2 - m^2 c^4} - mc^2$ where $P$ is the ordinary spatial momentum operator? If not, why isn't this an interesting/useful case?

Note: of course this is just the free particle case. This is the simplest case, which is why I'm asking about it.

Comment: there  was a question about this last week: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541538/

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia's pages on [Relativistic Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics) and [Relativistic Wave Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_wave_equations) or similar ?

Comment: You’re talking about the [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein–Gordon_equation).

Comment: @G.Smith I now realize it's the square-roto Klein Gordon equation. These I think are different in ways that matter.

Comment: @StephenG I've looked at them, but this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics) actually does reference this "square root Klein Gordon eq" which I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: The only way I know of to give meaning to a derivative inside a square root is to get rid of the square root by squaring. Do you have some other way to define it?

Comment: @G.Smith The spectral theorem for unbounded operators gives a "functional calculus" allowing us to make sense of functions of operators by defining them in a natural way for "basis" of generalized eigenvectors. In this case, we can use a momentum space representation of $\psi$, then $f(P) \psi(k) = f(k) \psi(k)$ for any function $f$.